# wp-includes does not contain a feed template

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, feed

Using Wordpress 3.9, I'm trying to create a custom feed template for a custom post type, which will include some custom fields.

Idea is to use this feed to to send out a "newsletter" type email once a month, with updates on newly added products.

The problem is that when I wanted to copy the code from the current feeds as a starting point for my custom feed, I couldn't find these pages anywhere.

According to the wordpress codex, these should be found within wp-includes. But they are not there. I checked a couple more folders... nothing.

Within wp-includes I do have a file called class.feed.php. But opening that really didn't give me any pointers.

I would need to remove the current custom post title from the field, as this is an empty field, and to add about 10 custom fields. So a completely new template seemed the easiest option.

Comment: try `wp-includes/feed-rss.php` or `wp-includes/feed-rss2.php`.

Comment: @Mayeenul Islam, I would love to, but they don't exist inside my wp-includes folder. None of the suggested files in the codex appear in my wp-includes folder... . Still, I have a working feed. So the template must be loaded from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a complete file and database Backup, you can **Re-install** your WordPress again
[image: Update WordPress]

As the image says, just click on the <kbd>Re-install Now</kbd> button to Re-install your WordPress setup.

Hope it'll avail all the default WordPress files.